# avoiding Event records to duplicate in a table when using cron.schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cron-task

Hope someone here could help me with some logic and code when using cron.schedule.

My issue what I am trying to is kind of flagging a event to not store a duplicate event in a table every minute, but rather once and once only when using cron.scheduler.

so what happens is every minute the scheduler populates the same result of the same id in the table duplicating it I want it to only store it once.

Hope this makes sense?

This is my Cron.scheduler below

```
 cron.schedule('0 */1 * */1 *', function(){
      autoTicketCloseReminder();
  });
```

Comment: It looks like it's not a problem with your cron timing, but more like a problem with `autoTicketCloseReminder` function (if you can, please provide implementation of it). You need to implement inside that function the logic for not overwriting the entry if it exists.
On the other hand, you can use a more sophisticated job schedulers like Agenda and Bull where you can schedule only one event.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I wish I could provide more of the function implementations and code, but unfortunately it's against company policy :( 

but I'll see if i can try the other schedulers ideas.